# Display continuously change of an image in python

Tags: python

I am writing a python program that gradually changes an image step by step, adjusting each pixel by a small amount in each step. To get a visualization of what the program is doing during runtime, I want it to display the image at each step, always overwriting the currently shown image so that it doesen't open  bunch of display windows.

I already tried matplotlib, opencv and skimage, with their according possibilities to display an image and update the frame content in the course of the program:

```py
# using scimage
viewer = ImageViewer(image)
viewer.show(main_window=False) # set the parameter to false so that the code doesn't block here but continues computation
..other code..
viewer.update_image(new_image)

# using matplotlib
myplot = plt.imshow(image)
plt.show(block=False)
.. other code..
myplot.set_data(new_image)
plt.show()

# using opencv
cv2.imshow('image',image)
.. other code ..
cv2.imshow('image', new_image)
```

I always ran into the problem that when it was supposed to open a frame with an image, it did not display the image but only a black screen. Weirdly enough, when I ran the code in IntelliJ in debug-mode and hit a breakpoint after the display-function, it worked.

What can I do so that it is displayed correctly when running the program normally and not with a breakpoint?

Comment: Can you show what you coded so far ? Do you want to set certain pixels or do you plot something. Do you want to copy images onto other images ? There are so many image modules that it is hard to tell what suits your needs.

Comment: @areop-enap I updated my question, I hope it gives a clearer picture now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing, I think your program does work, except it does and finishes unless you tell it to **pause**, which is why your breakpoint strategy is working.

<strike>Try pausing after showing image -</strike>

- You can ask for user input. It'll pause until you enter some input to the program.
- Put the program thread to sleep for some specified amount of time. This'll freeze your program for some given specified time, but you'll be able to see the image if it's already rendered.

**Edit -**

Since opencv's `waitKey` method is working for you now, you can use this method again to prevent the program from closing image window. Use `waitKey(0)` as your last program statement. It waits for a key press indefinitely, and returns the pressed key's code. Press any key to continue (but remember to have your image window in focus or it won't work), and your program should close if it's used in the end.

Also, I've striked earlier suggested options for pausing a program, because I'm unsure if it would've helped. I think `waitKey` method is more complex, and helps pause the program without freezing it.

Comment: yes, he could do it by calling `temp = input ( "hit enter to continue" )`

Comment: Unfortunately that idoes not work for my case. Consider the image displaying more like a debugging output, like a visual log line. During the program run the image is iteratively adjusted about 60 times, each step taking a few 100ms, so it would be way too much overhead to wait a few seconds each iteration or require a user input

Comment: @Josef, Please try `cv2.waitKey(5)` after each of `cv2.imshow()` method calls. 5ms delay each frame shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer, I was occupied otherwise. The `waitKey`-Method worked! Now all I got left is to keep the image frame opened and do not close it when the program ends, but I will find a solution for that. If you add this solution to your answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am still not sure what exactly your goal is but here is a code piece that modifies an image inside of a window whenever the upper button is pressed.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, Label, PhotoImage, mainloop
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600

def modify_image():
  print ("modifiying image...")
  for x in range(1000):
    img.put ( '#%06x' % random.randint(0, 16777215),   # 6 char hex color
      ( random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT) )   # (x, y)
    )
  canvas.update_idletasks()
  print ("done")

canvas = Canvas(Tk(), width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#000000")
canvas.pack()

Button(canvas,text="modifiying image",command=modify_image).pack()
img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
Label(canvas,image=img).pack()
mainloop()
```

The function `modify_image()` adds 1000 random pixels to the image within the main window. Note the tkinter module is a default python module.